# How can I change the language in Pokémon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

My game is currently in French, probably because my phone is in French.

I would like to change the language of Pokémon GO because I always played Pokémon in English and, as a result, I don't know the names of the Pokémon in French.

Is it possible for me to change the language of Pokemon GO to English? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent update, you can now change the in-game language of Pokemon Go without having to go through the hoops of change your device settings. The default language uses the device settings, but you can change it to any of the supported languages. To change this, go to Menu -> Settings -> Language

[image: Change language]

Answer (score 10):

For Android, Pokemon GO appears to use your device's set language.

In order to change the game language, you need to change the language of your phone.

For iOS, you will need to use [Jake's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272894/76693).

Answer (score 6):

I live in Japan and the app is in Japanese with my phone being in English. Unfortunately, I think the only way to change the language on iOS is to create an Apple ID in the country that speaks the language you want to use and download it from that App Store.

Comment: Well I changed the language of my phone and it worked! Maybe because I have an Android...

Comment: Well for me it is sufficient to change the phone's language to get another language in pokemon. However, I would like to have a language that differs from my phone's ... :( I have an iPhone 6

Answer (score 1):

in IOS, just go to Setting, scroll down to APPs, find Pokemon Go/Preferred Language, then you chose the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, simply change the country in your Apple iD. Don't know much about android. I found this alternative solution here. [change language pokemon go](http://www.letspokemongo.com/change-launguage-pokemon-go/)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS if you have a apple music subscription you can't change the region/language of your app store sadly. Most games though already have an in-game option for that so until now it wasn't a problem. Niantic should really add the option please create a poll or something on the official forum for that!

Answer (score -1):

In ios it doesnt matter which apple id you used. I used US but my pokemon is in german same as phone language. Only way to change it is by changing whole phone setting. 
Personaly i would also prefer having english pokemon on german iphone :/