# Pokemon Go language problems pls help

Tags: pokemon-go

I have downloaded the app "Pokemon Go" but it seems to be in Japanese I don't speak Japanese and do not know how to solve this problem !! Can somebody pls help me I am dying to play the game

Answer (score 0):

```
For Android, Pokemon GO appears to use your device's set language.

In order to change the game language, you need to change the language of your phone.
```

[**Source**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272843/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go)

Comment: pls dont copy an answer from another question that is asking the same thing. instead flag this question as a duplicate of the other question that has the information

Comment: Additionally to what @Dragonrage said: please don't write an answer to a question after you have flagged it for closure. Close votes are not meant for monopolizing answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new here. This was never my intention, I won't do it again. :)